# What do these Japanese characters mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

Sorry, but cannot find it. Could you tell what does it mean?

And which symbol is correct writing on keyboard?

Can i type it?

[image: hieroglyph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is 一 `番` (it is written from top to bottom) it is read "ichi ban" and it means "number one" in the sense of "best".

Could be also just indicate the number one, but in this case since I see the writing "Japan" below it I suppose is from a souvenir and hence the meaning is probably as I said in the beginning.